# How to account for the beam weight in a torque question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Supposing there are two objects on each side of a beam (at different distances), for the beam to be balanced the net torque must be 0. But how do we account for the beam's weight?

Comment: Assume all the weight of the beam is acting at its centre of mass.

Answer (score 0):

The beam's weight acts at the mid point. For example, if the beam is of 1m, the weight of the beam acts at 50cm mark. If the fulcrum is at 50cm, then the weight will not create any moment.

If the fulcrum is to the left of the mid point, then the weight of the beam will add on to the clockwise moment.

If the fulcrum is to the right of the mid point, then the weight of the beam will add on to the anticlockwise moment.

I wish you know the Principle of Moments, so I'm not going into an explanation here.

Comment: Please note that the Principle of Moments is the same as the equality of torque on both sides to balance the beam.

Comment: You can also treat the mass as a distributed load across the beam.  I wouldn't recommend it if you can assume the bar is infinitely stiff (as we probably can here); but if you ever get into mechanics of materials/deformable bodies; it's worth noting that the mass of the beam will actually be spread out across it.

Comment: I do know that, but I don't know whether the question is in basic level or advanced level. So, I gave that explanation.

Comment: Oh absolutely, I'm just pointing out that it's an assumption that can fall apart if you're not careful for when you apply it.

Comment: I think I got the correct answer but as in this case the pivot, that is actually a string, is located to the left I accounted for its weight (the beam's) adding to both clockwise and anticlockwise moments, relative to the distance from the pivot. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you cannot add the torque to both sides. In your case, torque will get added only to clockwise part.

Comment: But at what distance should I consider it then?

Comment: I think I figured it out: is it the distance of the pivot from its Centre of Gravity?

Comment: The distance will be the distance of the centre of mass (50cm mark in my case) from the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

As Wrichik said, the entire weight of the beam acts on its Centre of Gravity, it is the point located on the body at such a place that if we pivot that point then the net torque of all the particles of that beam would be equal to zero. We will therefore assume that the mass of the beam is evenly distributed throughout, so if it has its fulcrum at the midpoint, then the torque caused by its weight would be zero, if the fulcrum is at the right side, the weight of the beam would cause Anticlockwise moment, if it is on the left side the weight of the beam would cause Clockwise moment, because now the centre of gravity is not coinciding with the centre of mass of the beam, in order to stabilise it.